# distro 'rhel7.2' does not exist in our dictionary

Tags: virtual-machine, rhel, kvm, libvirt

While installing a kvm via virt-install I have used following attribute `os_variant=rhel7.2`. While installing I am getting following error :

```
distro 'rhel7.2' does not exist in our dictionary
```

When I do `uname -r` I am getting output as

```
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
```

It is a RHEL KVM host. 
Running `osinfo-query os|grep 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2'` returns following:

```
rhel7.1              | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2                       | 7.2      | http://redhat.com/rhel/7.2
```

What can be solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom config file to define a RHEL-7.2 distro, but it is honestly not that important from virt-install's POV. The distro is used to lookup the optimized drivers to use for disk & network primarily. Just using the 'rhel7.1' distro type when installing 'rhel-7.2' will work just fine from this POV.

Comment: In  that case, will using rhel7 distro type won't cause any problem?

Comment: At most it could mean some defaults may be configured with sub-optimal values but that's not the case for any rhel-7.x, since there's been no need for changes in defaults between minor releases yet.

Answer (score 2):

virt-install get's it's os information out of [osinfo-db](https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/osinfo-db)

If your os does not ship a recent version of osinfo-db you can manually download it from https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/ and import it.
e.g.

```
wget https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/osinfo-db-20200325.tar.xz
osinfo-db-import -v osinfo-db-20200325.tar.xz
```

-v will display all imported os'es, I believe your choice has to match one of the xml files in this list.